# How to copy all files and directories except one from local drive to HDFS?

Tags: bash, hadoop, hdfs

I have a directory `/home/my_directory/` that contains the following files and sub-directories:

```
anotherTest.txt  doNotCopy.txt   my_subdirectory/   subdirectory2/   test.txt
```

How can I copy all files and directories on HDFS except `doNotCopy.txt` file?

Comment: Use rsync `rsync --exclude=PATTERN`

Comment: @Ivan rsync doesnt work with HDFS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--copyFromLocal` does not give a way to exclude particular files. What you can do is the following:

```
ls /home/my_directory | grep -v 'doNotCopy.txt' | while read -r fileName ; do 
    eval "hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal -f $fileName /path/to/HDFS/" 
done
```

Now if you `ls` your `/path/to/HDFS/` you should get the desired files in there:

```
hdfs dfs -ls -C /path/to/HDFS/

anotherTest.txt   my_subdirectory/   subdirectory2/   test.txt
```

**If you want to exclude multiple files or directories**

```
ls /home/my_directory | grep -v 'doNotCopy.txt\|dirDoNotCopy\|anotherTextFile.txt' | while read -r fileName ; do 
    eval "hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal -f $fileName /path/to/HDFS/" 
done
```